# Numpy Use 2D array as heightmap-like index for 3D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, heightmap

I want to use a 2D array as an index for a 3D array as a heightmap to index axis 0 of the 3D array. Is there an efficient "numpy-way" of doing this? In my example I want to set everything at equal or greater height of the heightmap in each corresponding pillar two zero. Example:
3D Array:

```
[[[1, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 1]],
 [[1, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 1]],
 [[1, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 1]],
 [[1, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 1]]]
```

2D Array (heightmap):

```
[[0, 1, 2],
 [2, 3, 4],
 [2, 0, 0]]
```

Desired output:

```
[[[0, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 1],
  [1, 0, 0]],
 [[0, 0, 1],
  [1, 1, 1],
  [1, 0, 0]],
 [[0, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 1],
  [0, 0, 0]],
 [[0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 1],
  [0, 0, 0]]]
```

So far I have implemented this with a for python loop as in

```
for y in range(arr2d.shape[0]):
    for x in range(arr2d.shape[1]):
        height = arr2d[y, x]
        arr3d[height:, y, x] = 0
```

but this seems very ineffecient and I feel like there might be a way better way to do this.

Comment: `arr3d[arr2d, np.arange(3)[:,None], np.arange(3)] = 0`.  Make arrays for 2 and 3rd axes that broadcast with `arr2d`.  In effect replace the `range` with `arange` - generating all indices at once rather than one by one.

Comment: @hpaulj that gives me `array([[[0, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 0]],

       [[1, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1]],

       [[1, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 1],
        [0, 1, 1]],

       [[1, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1]]])`
which is not really what I was looking for.

Comment: I missed the fact that you are setting a slice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drawing inspiration from an fast way of padding arrays:

```
In [104]: (np.arange(4)[:,None,None]<arr2d).astype(int)                                          
Out[104]: 
array([[[0, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0]]])
```

Comment: To have this work with any values in arr3d not just 1 and 0, I used 
`arr3d[np.bitwise_not(np.arange(4)[:,None,None] < arr2d)] = 0`.